# Rails error with where clause in update_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a table without primary key with three columns - Player_ID, Season and Amount. When  I want to update my current table I have this error message: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'salaries.' in 'where clause': UPDATE `salaries` SET `Season` = 20192, `Amount` = 3232.0 WHERE `salaries`.`` IS NULL)

Update method in my controller:

```
def new
  @salary = Salary.new
  @players = Player.all
  @title = "Add salary"
end

def create
  @players = Player.all
  @salary = Salary.new(params[:salary])
  if @salary.save
    flash[:success] = "Successfully added salary"
    redirect_to salaries_path
  else
    @title = "Add salary"
    render 'new'
  end
end

def edit
  @player_id = params[:player_id]
  @season = params[:season]
  @salary = Salary.find_by_Player_ID_and_Season(params[:player_id], params[:season])
  @players = Player.all
  @title = "Edit salary"
end

def update
    @players = Player.all
    @player_id = params[:player_id]
    @season = params[:season]
    @salary = Salary.find_by_Player_ID_and_Season(params[:player_id], params[:season])
    if @salary.update_attributes(params[:salary])
       flash[:success] = "Successfully edited salary"
       redirect_to salaries_path
    else
       render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@salary, :url => salary_path(:player_id => @player_id, :season => @season)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :Player_ID, @players, :ID, :Name %>
  <%= f.text_field :Season %>
  <%= f.text_field :Amount %>
  <%= f.submit "Add" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Sounds like your salary table doesn't have a primary key

Comment: Yes, it is. A don't have a primary key. I have three columns - Player_ID, Season and Amount. I want to edit some of my rows in the db. That's my aim.

Answer (score 1):

Active Record models have to have a primary key or rows can't be updated or delete.

There is a `composite_primary_keys` gem if you really don't want to add an ID column to your table (although adding that primary key is certainly the path of least resistance)

Comment: `primary key` was the problem. Had some issues with the `create table` migration. Thanks for bringing this thing up.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your table has already primary key! It's the `id` attribute.
The `params[:season]` ... i think it's `params[:salary][:season]`, right?
I think you should write in downcase `season, player_id, amount`. After that, if it still has problem, post new code here^^

Comment: I am not sure that I understand you. How I have a primary key id? And why it should  be params[:salary][:season]? And attribtes are not written in downcase because my columns are  Season, Player_ID and  Amount.

Comment: "A primary key column called id will also be added, however since this is the default we do not need to ask for this." see here [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html)
the params[:salary][:season] instead params[:season] because the form for salary instance.

Answer (score 0):

I know the reason for your error, although the root cause isn't immediately clear to me. Your failing query is this:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'salaries.' in 'where clause': UPDATE salaries SET Season = 20192, Amount = 3232.0 WHERE salaries.`` IS NULL)
```

The important part is this:

```
WHERE salaries.`` IS NULL
```

It would make a certain amount of sense if it were `WHERE salaries.foo IS NULL` or `WHERE salaries.bar IS NULL`, but you just have empty space where a column name would normally be. So I guess MySQL (for some weird reason) is interpreting that to mean that you're talking about a column called `salaries` (i.e. `salaries.salaries`), which doesn't exist.

I don't even know why the `WHERE` clause is in there in the first place.

Does your `create` action work?

**Update:** the problem is almost certainly this line:

```
if @salary.update_attributes(params[:salary])
```

I believe what you want instead is:

```
if @salary.update_attributes(:amount => params[:amount])
```

See if that does anything.

Comment: Added in my post new, create and edit method. My create method works but my form is different there. First row is only <%= form_for(@salary) do |f| %>

Comment: Okay, here's my advice. First, make the `update` form match the `create` form. Make the `update` action as plain and simple as possible, and get it working. Then, little by little, adjust your form and controller code to match what you were originally after.

Comment: I did it many times before I posted this question but can't understand where is the problem with the where clause. The statement of where clause should be: "where salaries.player_id = player_id from url and salaries.season = season from url"

Comment: If I remove from _form.html ":url => salary_path(:player_id => @player_id, :season => @season)" I have an error message: "undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: This controller you're showing us is `app/controllers/salaries_controller.rb`, right?

Comment: Yes, it is salaries_controller.rb

Comment: Is it possible that the Player controller might be a better place to handle updating a player's salary information?

Comment: I don't think so. The error is somewhere in my salaries controller or form.html, I am sure.

Comment: I found the problem. It is that params[:salary] is nil but I can't understand why it is.

Comment: `params[:salary]` is nil because you don't have any input field called "salary" (nor should you). I think what you're after is `params[:amount]`. See my updated answer.

Comment: It isn't working. My query now is: "UPDATE `salaries` SET `Player_ID` = NULL, `Season` = NULL, `Amount` = NULL WHERE `salaries`.`` IS NULL". If I change params[:amount] to params[:salary][:amount], the query is: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'salaries.' in 'where clause': UPDATE `salaries` SET `Season` = 2040, `Amount` = 300.0 WHERE `salaries`.`` IS NULL. But the problem  is again with the where clause and why it is nil instead oft "Player_ID => 1 and Season => 2013"

Comment: Maybe @salary = Salary.find_by_Player_ID_and_Season(params[:player_id], params[:season]) is nil and that's the problem

Comment: Instead of finding by `player_id` and `season`, why not go by `salary.id`? Also, you're probably right about those params being nil. You probably need `params[:Player_ID]` and `params[:Season]`. You should really rename all your columns, inputs, etc. to all lowercase, though. That's the way people seem to always do it in Rails.

Comment: You'll probably need `params[:Amount]` for amount, too. But once you get this working, I really do recommend renaming everything to lowercase.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17672/discussion-between-user1107922-and-jason-swett)